# avconv simultaneously stream from usb webcam and save video onto disk

Tags: output, libav, simultaneous, avconv

I need to simultaneously stream/broadcast (over rtmp) and save video (with audio) from my USB webcam. The webcam is Logitech c920 which have hardware h.264 encoder.

I don't want to reencode the media, so I'm using the `-c:v copy` option.

The whole script looks like below:

```
#! /bin/bash

SOURCEV="/dev/video0"
SOURCEA="hw:1"

FILE_TO_SAVE="Archive/file_to_save.mp4"
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
KEY="my-secret-key"        

avconv -f alsa -ac 2 -r 44100 -i $SOURCEA \
-s 1920x1080 -r 24 -c:v h264 -i "$SOURCEV" \
-ar "44100" -r:v 24 -c:a aac -c:v copy -s 1920x1080 -f mp4 "$FILE_TO_SAVE" \
-g $FPS*4 -ar "44100" -b:a "128k" -ac 2 -r 24 -c:a aac -c:v copy -s 1920x1080 -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

This method "works" - it means' it can stream content and save it to disk, but the problem with this method is that file video relies on the stream. For example if the Internet connection is too slow, the saved file will have low FPS. If the Internet connection is interrupted the "recording" of video file is stopped.

Can anyone help me with making this two streams independent?

The whole things is happening on raspberrypi 3 so computing power is highly limited.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install nginx + nginx-rtmp locally and stream to it. In options of server enable saving to local files. And launch other script to re-stream to youtube.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work quite stable, but youtube now warning me about my keyframe interval which is 10 sec. Is there any way to make it shorten? I've read this topic: [link](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/593)
But the h264_i_frame_period control is missing in my. The tricky yhing is that I'm able to set the iframe intervel using guvcview, but this setting seems to apply to current guvcview instance only,

Comment: This is encoder specific settings, nginx don't transcode video.

Comment: I know this isn't controlled by nginx. Just didn't wat to ask/open another question. Maybe someone know how to set the encoder keyframe interval to 100 frames?